# JavaScript learning, in writing the code

Tags: javascript

according to 1, When we calling the increment method. a is increasing with the given parameter to the function, if no parameter passed then it is inc by 1.

But according to 2, when i write the code like below, a is not inc, always 1 only. Why??.... Please solve this....

```
// 1
var Obj1 = {
    a: 0,
    increment: function(inc) {
        this.a += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

// 2
var Obj1 = {
    a: 0,
    increment: function(inc) {
        this.value = this.a + typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> when i write the code like below, a is not inc, always 1 only. Why??

Because you are never assigning any new value to `a`

Make it

```
var Obj1 = {
   a: 0,
   increment: function (inc) {
      this.a = this.value = this.a + typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
   }
};
```

or

```
var Obj1 = {
   a: 0,
   increment: function (inc) {
      this.value = this.a + typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
      this.a = this.value;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you need value but

```
    var Obj1 = {
     a: 0,
     increment: function (inc) {
       this.a = this.a + typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
     }
    };
```